# Simulating Smartphones on PC with Unity

Tags: unity, android, ios, iphone, simulations

I want to make a game that depends on the phone orientation (changing shoot direction with tilt), however I need to test this on PC. So is there any tool I can use to simulate the orientation of the phone with mouse or keyboard of my PC? Something like joysticks on the screen.

Thanks for any help!

### Edit :

Thanks to @jhocking for his suggestion of Unity Remote. I, however still can accept a solution with using only PC, since I'm afraid of shortening my phone's battery life, for some reason.

Comment: Why would this shorten your battery's life? Unless you simply mean "use up charge" rather than permanently shorten how long the charge lasts, in which case Unity Remote probably *charges* your battery, since you have to have the USB plugged in.

Comment: Yes it will use up, but I have always tried to avoid a big workload -such as constantly installing, playing and deleting my deployment- since I think as my battery is used, it will eventually shorten in life. I don't know about the technical details of the smartphone batteries but it's no secret that they are already very short-life. So I want to protect it no matter what :D

Answer (score 3):

[Unity Remote](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote4.html) exists for this purpose. Quoting their description:

> Unity Remote is an application that allows you to use your target
>   device as a remote control for your project in Unity editor. This is
>   useful during development since it is much quicker to test your
>   project in the editor with remote control than to build and deploy it
>   to the device after each change.

However if you don't want to use that tool for some reason and absolutely have to have test controls done using a joystick or keyboard, just program alternate controls using [GetAxis("Horizontal")](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) and put this code inside a compiler directive [#if UNITY_EDITOR](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

Comment: Wow, great. Thanks! Any known issues? Like battery drainage, lag, inaccuracy etc. ?
Edit : And some say that it is Unity Pro only. Is it true? I'm using Unity Free.

Comment: I know not. Unity Remote is a free app so why don't you just download it and tell us if it works on Unity Free